# switching exception level el3 to el1

Tags: arm64

I was competed Enabled Quad core for Arm Cortex a53, now I want to trigger interrupt. The interrupt present in exception level 1 (EL1). There is an issue while I am switching EL3 to EL1. When I jump to el1 entry symbol it is going to hanging in synchronous exception handler(cxsynx). Where I did mistake in this scenario.kindly let me know

```
mov x3, #(SCR_EL3_RW  | \
          SCR_EL3_SMD | \
          SCR_EL3_NS)      // Set NS bit, to access Non-secure registers
msr SCR_EL3, x3
mov x0, #(HCR_EL2_RW)
msr hcr_El2, x0
// Initialize the SCTLR_EL1 register before entering EL1.
MSR SCTLR_EL1, XZR

mov x0, #15
msr ICC_SRE_EL2, x0
isb
msr ICC_SRE_EL1, x0 // Non-secure copy of ICC_SRE_EL1

//
// Get the current state and exception level
mrs x0, CurrentEL
and x1, x0, #0xC
lsr x1, x1, #2



// Set the target PC_EL1 to the exception handler address
adr x3, el1_entry_aarch64
msr elr_el3, x3

mrs x1, SPSR_EL3
msr daifset, #0xF

mrs x2, SPSR_EL3
mov x2, #0x3C5
msr SPSR_EL3, x2

//Enabling IRQ by clearing bit
mrs x0, daif
bic x0, x0, #(1 << 7)
msr daif, x0

//Disabling IRQ by masking bit
mrs x0, daif
orr x0, x0, #(1 << 7)
msr daif, x0

// Switch to EL1
eret
```

When I jump to el1 entry symbol it is going to hanging in synchronous exception handler(cxsynx).

Comment: Look at `ESR_EL1` to see why it faulted.

Comment: Once jump into el1entry function. it's going to hanging. Where to check it out ESR_EL1 register.